# Laravel route - finding instance of a post even when it should not be able to

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on post system for a webpage and I found a weird interaction so I would like to ask if there is any way to prevent this from happening.

my route:

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}', ...);
```

and the controller:

```
public function show($post)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($post);
    return view('Posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

The interaction is that even something like /posts/2adasdasjndajg can return an instace of Post with ID 2 which I would prefer if it failed since only an ID should be in the link in order to find the correct post. Thanks

Comment: Add one more column in the table, ex. seo_url, while you insert the record in post save with id and post title, for example, 2adasdasjndajg, here 2 => Id and adasdasjndajg => post title => then while fetching  `$post = Post::where('seo_url', $post)-firstOrFail();` , It may help you.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will be work reference [click](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-create-a-route-with-slug-and-id)

Route

```
Route::get('/posts/{param}', ...);
```

Controller

```
public function show($param)
{
    $post = Post::where('id', $param)
            ->orWhere('slug', $param)
            ->firstOrFail();
    return view('Posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **firstOrFail** and search both in slug and id,

```
    public function show($post)
    {
        $post = Post::where('id', $post)->orWhere('slug', $post)->firstOrFail();
        return view('Posts.show', compact('post'));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain the route parameter with a pattern to only be an integer instead of accepting a string which will then get converted:

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', ...)->where('post', '[0-9]+');
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing - Route Parameters - Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) `where`

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a regular expression match to find ID from the url, For example if you have `2adasdasjndajg` in the url, with the following code you can detect ID and find the post.

```
$pattern = "/^[0-9]+/i";
preg_match($pattern, $post,$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); 
$id = $matches[0][0];

$post = Post::findOrFail($post);
return view('Posts.show', compact('post'));
```